# while uploading large video 'system.outofmemoryexception' thrown

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to uplaod video with upload handler, but while uploading large video file `system.outofmemoryexception` thrown. my code is below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using SageFrame.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRuntimeSection configSection = new HttpRuntimeSection();
        context.Response.Write(configSection.MaxRequestLength);  
        HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        HttpFileCollection myfile = Request.Files;  ////Here i get error     
    }
}
```

i am using `VS2010` thanks.

Comment: What about google search about **system.outofmemoryexception**?? Have a look at **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w766t6y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx**. I think might need to change **httpRuntime Element**

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you probably need to change the HttpRuntime maxRequestLength attribute to allow for your large file sizes. The size specified is in kilobytes, example below sets it to 100MB:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```